# Cakephp Ajax pagination links doesnt work

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, pagination

I have a table where i want to use pagination my table data is filled in by Ajax.

This is the table im working with:

```
<div class="portlet box green Report index">
    <div class="portlet-title">
        <div class="caption"><i class="icon-globe"></i>Report Summary</div>
        <div class="tools">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-body">
    <div id="content">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" id="sample_1">
            <thead>
            <tr id='content2'>
                <?php //echo $content_for_layout; ?>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('clicks); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('conversions'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('payout'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('ltr'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('cpc'); ?></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="report_data">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On top of my view i have the following:

```
  $this->Paginator->options(array(
    'update' => '#content2',
    'evalScripts' => true,
));
```

And in my controller i have remembered to have the following helpers and components:

```
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'), 'Paginator');
```

And at the end of my view i have added:

```
<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>
```

Now whenever i click one of the table links the site reloads BUT there are two main problems:

1. The data sent back to the paginator does not contain a sort nor an order (aka the site is basicly just reloading)
2. The Render of the site is messing up (this is a minor problem but still very annoying)

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

**Cake version**
2.3

**My Cntroller**

```
    class ReportsController extends AppController
{
    public $name = 'Reports';

        public $components = array( 'BloglicHelper', 'RequestHandler', 'HasOffers');

        public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'), 'Paginator');
        public $paginate = array(
        'fields' => array(
         'Stat.clicks'
        ,'Offer.name'
        ,'Stat.currency'
        ,'Stat.conversions'
        ,'Stat.payout'
        ,'Stat.ltr'
        ,'Stat.cpc'
        ,'Stat.affiliate_id')

    ,'conditions' => array(    'Stat.affiliate_id' => array(
            'conditional' => "EQUAL_TO",
            'values' => array(1002)
        )

        , 'Stat.date' => array(
                'conditional' => 'BETWEEN'
            , 'values' => array(
                )
            ),
        ),
        'group' =>array('Offer.name'),
        'Method' => 'getStats',
        'totals' => true

    );
    public function index(){
        $this->layout = 'client_layout';
    }

    public function ajax_index(){
        if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())
        {
            $this->autoLayout = false;
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
        }

        //request selected dates
        $startDate = $this->request->data['startDateTime'];
        $endDate = $this->request->data['endDateTime'];

        array_push($this->paginate['conditions']['Stat.date']['values'], $startDate, $endDate);
;

        $finalData = array( 'table' => $this->paginate());
        print json_encode($finalData);

    }

}
```

Comment: what version of cakephp you are using ?

Comment: `>sort('name); ?` is this a typo? you're missing a quote

`sort('clicks); ?` here too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line at the top of your view file.

```
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'update' => '#content',
    'evalScripts' => true,
));
```

Here you have to update the whole table instead of only one row i.e. `#content2`

```
  <div class="portlet box green Report index">
    <div class="portlet-title">
        <div class="caption"><i class="icon-globe"></i>Report Summary</div>
        <div class="tools">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-body">
        <div id="content">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" id="sample_1">
                <thead>
                    <tr id='content2'>
                        <?php //echo $content_for_layout; ?>
                        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name'); ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('clicks'); ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('conversions'); ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('payout'); ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('ltr'); ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('cpc'); ?></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="report_data">
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <ul>
                <?php if ($this->Paginator->hasPrev()): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->first(__('First')) ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->prev(__('Prev'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled')) ?></li>
                    <?php
                endif;

                echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('currentTag' => 'span', 'currentClass' => 'active',
                    'separator' => false, 'tag' => 'li', 'modulus' => 5));

                if ($this->Paginator->hasNext()):
                    ?>
                    <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->next(__('Next'), array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled')) ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->last(__('Last')) ?></li>
                <?php endif ?>
            </ul>
           <?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

having some errors in

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name); ?></th>
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('clicks); ?></th>
```

these two lines

`<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>` should be inside the element which you want to update. i.e. here `#content`

you can get more information [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#making-ajax-links).

Comment: Ive checked and followed the documentation and i'm really glad for your help but sadly it did not change anything :S

Comment: when i press one of them it basicly just reloads the page. And the Html link when i hover on the links are not different from the site where i am..

Comment: is it generating any kind of script like this `$("#link-1647077326").bind("click", function (event) {$.ajax({beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {$("#UsersListingForm tbody").fadeOut();}, complete:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {$("#UsersListingForm tbody").fadeIn();}, dataType:"html", evalScripts:true, success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#UsersListingForm").html(data);}, url:"\/allUsers?sort=name&direction=asc"});
return false;});`

Comment: where `$("#link-1647077326")` is generated using `js helper`

Comment: the link looks like this <a id="link-1991726950" href="/bloglic-2013/cake/index.php/Reports">Conversions</a>

Comment: Wait there is a script il add the html in my question

Comment: I've reviewed your html what is the problem you're getting here

Comment: the problem is that it is not sorting i.e the request send to the paginate hasnt changed which means the links reloads the page instead of doing forexample #sort:name/direction:desc

Comment: `$("#link-529241123").bind("click", function (event) {$.ajax({dataType:"html", evalScripts:true, success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#content").html(data);}, url:"\/bloglic-2013\/cake\/index.php\/Reports"});
                                return false;});
                            `

Comment: In url you're not setting any paginate params here then how can you get pagination, can you add your controller code here, I think paginate params are not available here

Comment: This could be my problem: $("#link-547337522").bind("click", function (event) {$.ajax({dataType:"html", evalScripts:true, success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#content").html(data);}, url:"\/bloglic-2013\/cake\/index.php\/Reports"}); as you can see the link is reports which it should not be if it suppose to sorting

Comment: ive added my controller

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36734/discussion-between-marc-rasmussen-and-anil-kumar)